# How can I decline a call in iPhone when the screen was locked?

Tags: iphone, call

I have an iPhone 4S. I really don't know in which basis it shows Answer/Decline buttons when someone calling me. Sometimes it shows both buttons and sometimes it only show the option "Slide to answer".

[image]

The scenarios are,

- The iPhone is locked/unlocked
- The iPhone is in normal mode/silent mode

Note: I does not use Voice mail. I just need the "Decline" button in any mode/ any situation, because the mobile mode should not decide to hide the decline button. The owner of the mobile should decide it!

Comment: Are you on iOS 5 or 6?

Comment: I am having iOS5

Comment: same issue on iOS 7.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Push the power button on the top of the phone twice. The first time, the call is silenced. The 2nd time the call is rejected/directed to voice mail (if set up).

Comment: Thanks. Am I the only one who finds this totally non-obvious? :) Why aren't there buttons on the screen for this?

Comment: By the way, you can push any hardware button on the iPhone to silence a call, it doesn't have to be the power button.

Answer (score 13):

#### When the phone is locked (the screen is off)

On **iOS 6**, it show slide to answer and a little phone, that, when you slide it up, shows more options, such as accept / decline and more options.

On **iOS 5**, it only shows slide to answer. Like Mark said, tap the power button once to silence the call, twice to reject it.

#### When the phone is in use (screen on, unlocked)

On **All versions since the beginning of time**, it will show Accept / Deny buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Double-press the power button.

[image: Finger pressing power button]